# Case Expression in Group Clause - ELSE "Don't Group"

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE Jobs 
(
    JobNo int,
    Entered DATE,
    Linked int,
    Status varchar(255)
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO Jobs 
VALUES 
  (12345,'20211229',11135,'New'),
  (12345,'20211230',11135,'Cancelled'),
  (12346,'20221230',NULL,'New'),
  (12346,'20230101',NULL,'Cancelled'),
  (12345,'20230101',11135,'New'),
  (12346,'20230101',NULL,'New'),
  (12350,'20230101','12258','Billed'),
  (12351,'20230101',NULL,'New'),
  (12351,'20230101',NULL,'Cancelled'),
  (12351,'20230101',NULL,'New'),
  (12352,'20230102',NULL,'New'),
  (12353,'20230103','12249','New');

-- Test
SELECT JobNo 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE Status = 'New' AND Entered = '20230101' 
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN Linked IS NULL 
            THEN JobNo 
            ELSE NULL 
    END;

-- Returns 12345 and I want 12345,12351 (2 total)
```

I want to return from the table:

- Jobs 'Entered' on a specific date, with 'Status' = 'New'
- Don't include if job has 'New' status on a previous date, unless it has a 'Linked' value

Is this the right approach to the problem?

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: You don't need a GROUP BY at all - you're not doing any aggregation (SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX, COUNT, etc.). Your WHERE clause alone takes care of your requirement, and if it didn't, you would just need to add `AND linked IS NOT NULL`. You should find a good SQL tutorial to learn the basics - doing so will save you a lot of frustration.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: @Squirrel The expected result is 12345,12351.

Comment: @Ken White - I will need an aggregation or other filter at some point because I don't want duplicate JobNo returned. In the sample, removing the GROUP BY will return 12345,12346,12351,12351. I will also want rows returned when 'Linked' is NULL.

Comment: But you don't have one now, so the GROUP BY Is inappropriate. It is **ONLY** for use when aggregating data.  And you wouldn't use GROUP BY to prevent multiple JOBNOs anyway - that would be done with DISTINCT. These are a couple of the basic things that you would learn with that tutorial I suggested. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you need is a LEFT JOIN to the secondary criteria vs the first.

Start your query to get distinct NEW jobs on the date in question.

```
SELECT distinct
      j.JobNo 
   FROM 
      Jobs j
   WHERE 
          j.Status = 'New' 
      AND j.Entered = '2023-01-01'
```

Now this results (from the sample data)

```
JobNo
12345  (you want)
12346  (you want excluded)
12351  (you want)
```

Netxt, a list of all jobs with NEW status PRIOR to the date in question.  While at it, get a status of any "linked" entries such as...

```
select
      j.JobNo,
      max( case when j.Linked > 0 then 1 else 0 end ) HasAnyLinked
   from
      jobs j
   where
          j.entered < '2023-01-01'
      AND j.Status = 'New'
   group by
      j.JobNo
```

Resulting from your sample data

```
JobNo   HasAnyLinked
12345   1
12346   0
```

So, lets pull together

```
with WhatYouWant as
( the first query
),
LinkedJobs as
( the second query )

select
      w.*
   from
      WhatYouWant w
         LEFT JOIN LinkedJobs lj
            on w.JobNo = lj.JobNo
   where
         -- no prior "new" job entries
         lj.JobNo is null
         -- there WERE prior entries, but it HAS a link id
      OR lj.HasAnyLink = 1
```

At least if I am reading your question correctly.

Comment: This is a nice approach and answers my question. Thank you!
*Last line typo in answer changed to "OR lj.HasAnyLinked = 1"

Answer (score 1):

Your linked has no NULL Values instead it uses empty strings, if your original data has NULL you need to change the last WHERE criteria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JobNo FROM Jobs 
WHERE Status = 'New' AND Entered = '2023-01-01' AND Linked = ''
```

| JobNo |
| --- |
| 12346 |
| 12351 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0ijaC9ay)

Answer (score 0):

For your test you had no null values SO I set those up for a test as described.

```
;WITH jobs AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( VALUES
     (12345,'2021-12-29',11135,'New'),
     (12345,'2021-12-30',11135,'Cancelled'),
     (12346,'2022-12-30',NULL,'New'),
     (12346,'2023-01-01',NULL,'Cancelled'),
     (12345,'2023-01-01',11135,'New'),
     (12346,'2023-01-01',NULL,'New'),
     (12350,'2023-01-01','12258','Billed'),
     (12351,'2023-01-01',NULL,'New'),
     (12351,'2023-01-01',NULL,'Cancelled'),
     (12351,'2023-01-01',NULL,'New'),
     (12352,'2023-01-02',NULL,'New'),
     (12353,'2023-01-03','12249','New')
     ) AS j ( JobNo ,  Entered ,  Linked , Status)
 ) 

SELECT
    JobNo 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE Status = 'New' 
    AND Entered = '2023-01-01'
    AND Linked IS NULL
GROUP BY JobNo;
```

Now for this specific case you want to GROUP BY JobNo which is OK however since  that uses ALL the columns in the SELECT it is effectively the same as DISTINCT.

Here is another test showing the same results returned:

```
;WITH jobs AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( VALUES
     (12345,'2021-12-29',11135,'New'),
     (12345,'2021-12-30',11135,'Cancelled'),
     (12346,'2022-12-30',NULL,'New'),
     (12346,'2023-01-01',NULL,'Cancelled'),
     (12345,'2023-01-01',11135,'New'),
     (12346,'2023-01-01',NULL,'New'),
     (12350,'2023-01-01','12258','Billed'),
     (12351,'2023-01-01',NULL,'New'),
     (12351,'2023-01-01',NULL,'Cancelled'),
     (12351,'2023-01-01',NULL,'New'),
     (12352,'2023-01-02',NULL,'New'),
     (12353,'2023-01-03','12249','New')
     ) AS j ( JobNo ,  Entered ,  Linked , Status)
 ) 

SELECT DISTINCT
    JobNo 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE Status = 'New' 
    AND Entered = '2023-01-01'
    AND Linked IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm getting 12346,12351 returned, but expecting 12345,12351

Comment: This is probably because I interpreted the "it" differently here "Don't include if job has 'New' status on a previous date, **unless it has a 'Linked' value**" due to that  quesiton ambiguity.

Comment: An expected results  in the question would have enhanced your question clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think people are confused by your requirements. In particular:

> Don't include if job has 'New' status on a previous date, unless it has a 'Linked' value

What you need is a `NOT EXISTS` clause.

So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    JobNo 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE Status = 'New' 
    AND Entered = '2023-01-01';
```

Will get you records where the status is 'New' for the date '2023-01-01', now you need to handle the rest.

```
SELECT DISTINCT JobNO
FROM Jobs A
Where Status = 'New'
AND Entered = '2023-01-01'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Jobs B
    Where A.JobNo = B.JobNo
    AND B.Entered < A.Entered
    AND B.Status = 'New'
    AND A.Linked = '')
```

So the Not Exists checks for a record with the same JobNo on an earlier date with status of 'New' when the original record has no Linked status and only selects the original record if it can't find one.